# ATTiny414 inline assembly operand constraints for IO pin parameter

Tags: avr, attiny, assembly, avr-gcc

I'm trying to use the [light_ws2812](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812/tree/master/light_ws2812_AVR) library to drive WS2812 LEDs from an ATTiny414.
The core of that library is an inline assembly snippet that bitbangs the serial line. here it is with the timing-nops stripped out:

```
void inline ws2812_sendarray_mask(uint8_t *data,uint16_t datlen,uint8_t maskhi)
{
  uint8_t curbyte,ctr,masklo;
  uint8_t sreg_prev;

  ws2812_DDRREG |= maskhi; // Enable output

  masklo  =~maskhi&ws2812_PORTREG;
  maskhi |=        ws2812_PORTREG;

  sreg_prev=SREG;
  cli();  

  while (datlen--) {
    curbyte=*data++;

    asm volatile(
    "       ldi   %0,8  \n\t"
    "loop%=:            \n\t"
    "       out   %2,%3 \n\t"    //  '1' [01] '0' [01] - re
    "       sbrs  %1,7  \n\t"    //  '1' [03] '0' [02]
    "       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [--] '0' [03] - fe-low
    "       lsl   %1    \n\t"    //  '1' [04] '0' [04]
    "       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [+1] '0' [+1] - fe-high

    "       dec   %0    \n\t"    //  '1' [+2] '0' [+2]
    "       brne  loop%=\n\t"    //  '1' [+3] '0' [+4]
    :  "=&d" (ctr)
    :  "r" (curbyte), "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(ws2812_PORTREG)), "r" (maskhi), "r" (masklo)
    );
  }

  SREG=sreg_prev;
}
```

An obvious difference between the 'regular AVR' and the ATTiny*14 series
 C definitions is that the IO registers aren't called DDRx and PORTx but PORTx.DIR and PORTx. I already fixed that in the `light_ws2812` header and it seems to work fine.

After this I am however getting an error with the assembly operand 2 (`"I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(ws2812_PORTREG))`):

```
lib/light_ws2812.c: In function 'ws2812_sendarray_mask':
lib/light_ws2812.c:119:5: warning: asm operand 2 probably doesn't match constraints
     asm volatile(
     ^~~
lib/light_ws2812.c:119:5: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
make: *** [Makefile:28: lib/light_ws2812.o] Error 1
```

I also tried using a lowercase `i` as the constraint instead of the `I`, which changes the error to

```
/tmp/ccBR4JKE.s:48: Error: operand out of range: 1028
```

Looking at [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001912A.pdf) this value makes sense, `PORTA` starts at `0x400` (1024) and the `PORTx.OUT` register has an additional offset of 4 bytes, placing `PORTA.OUT` at `0x404 = 1028`.

with a 16-bit register constraint like `x` or `w` it compiles but then I get a linker error:

```
avr-ld: lib/light_ws2812.o: in function `loop32':
light_ws2812.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `r30'
```

I am compiling this using `avr-gcc` and `avr-ld`, with a current `avr-libc` that I manually added the relevant files from the `Atmel ATtiny Series Device Support` package to.

Comment: perhaps I should be using the `VPORTA.OUT` register instead? It starts at `0x0` so unlike `PORTA.OUT` it should fit into `i`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but there was never any clear answer, so here goes.

What worked for me was to replace `_SFR_IO_ADDR(ws2812_PORTREG)` with the following: `_SFR_ADDR(VPORTA.OUT)`

Why not `_SFR_IO_ADDR`? Well, that macro deducts the old offset of 0x20, which is not relevant in the new series. `_SFR_ADDR(x)` just converts `x` into the address of `x`, which is what we want in this case.

Edit: I happened to use PORTA in this case, but obviously you can use whatever port you want :)

Answer (score 2):

The ATTiny 1-series has the GPIO registers mapped outside of the io port register space, so they cannot be accessed using `out` or `in`. You will either need to use the VPORT registers, or load the address of the io port into a register and use an `st` instruction to write the data. If you decide to use a regular store instruction, it may change the timing of the loop so you may have to adjust the number of `nop`s.

Comment: Great, I had also come to a similar conclusion after I finally understood how to read the overall memory-layout from the datasheet.

Would there be an advantage in using the bit-addressing instructions to set the pin?

Comment: I'm not sure about the tiny414, but the overall AVR arch defines `st` as taking 2 cycles, whereas `out` takes 1 cycle.

Comment: I think it would `SBI` and `CBI`. Since they are all single-cycle instructions I suppose there is no difference (except in that if there was a peripheral active we wouldn't/couldn't overwrite their values in the port register, but I'm not sure if that is actually a possible problem).

I will check if this works as expected when I get home and accept the answer :)

Comment: okay, I couldn't get my code to work yet but thats likely unrelated to the question since the original code with the `"I"` constraint now works with VPORT*.

Comment: I know this topic is old, but I am trying to do the same thing (control WS2812 with ATtiny414) and I was wondering what solution did you finally find and what modifications did you do to the library?

Comment: @NicuBaciu See my answer :)